# Is the battle difficulty increased on subsequent matches?

Tags: card-hunter

In the campaign mode of Card Hunter, if you win a battle and play it again the next day for extra loot, is the difficulty changed at all? I noticed that I was having trouble winning battles that I had already won at lower levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battle difficulty does not change by default. However, at some point a "hard mode" is supposed to be implemented that you can select while replaying battles. However, that does not appear to be implemented yet, although I have not completed campaign mode so it might be new-game-plus content.

When you first click on the map icon for a 'play session', it brings up a description of that series of battles where it shows a "regular battle" check box. At the moment there are no other checkable boxes for me, but maybe there are for you. Make sure that is checked next time.